# what's the difference between the file format of a.dylib and dylib

Tags: ios, objective-c

There are two files in my mac, `libpcap.dylib` and `libpcap.A.dylib`. I wonder if there are any differences about them?

Answer (score 3):

The former is a symlink to the latter, at least on my system. You can use `ls` from Terminal to inspect the files.

```
macmini:stackoverflow samm$ ls -l /usr/lib/libpcap.*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  449040 Jul 23  2011 /usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      15 Jul 23  2011 /usr/lib/libpcap.dylib -> libpcap.A.dylib
macmini:stackoverflow samm$
```

I don't know if the `.A.dylib` suffix is special, [looking at the `libpcap` Makefile](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libpcap/libpcap-29/Makefile) I can see it is explicitly created in the `install` rule

```
$(LN) -s libpcap.A.dylib $(DSTROOT)/usr/lib/libpcap.dylib
```

Comment: Nice one!  I was also curious about this.

Comment: It's versioning.  You'll notice DyLibs like lXML do the same thing: Alias a standard bundle to a more specific version of the dylib.

Comment: Thank you for your anwsers.Now I feel that I have a long way to go.Much conceptin is new for me.